# Why do I get a NullPointerException when returning an object after mocking?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, mockito, powermock

The object returned is always `null` after mocking my `File` class. Why?

```
PowerMockito.whenNew(File.class).withArguments(String.class).thenReturn(configFile);
```

`configFile` being a `File` which is created like this in the test function:

```
@Test
public void loadJSONConfigFileTest() throws Exception {
   final File configFile = folder.newFile("config.json");
}
```

It's not `null`. The code that is supposed to get the returned `configFile`:

```
final File configFile = new File(pathFile);
```

Since the `File.class` with arguments is mocked, when this line is executed, the `configFile` is returned. But it's `null`.

Comment: can you paste a runnable program?

Comment: Can you post the code where the new File() is called ? There's not enough information to help you.

Comment: Also are you sure `configFile` is initialized and not null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `withArguments` incorrectly. It's not expecting a class, it's expecting the actual instance.

Try this:

```
PowerMockito.whenNew(File.class)
      .withArguments(Mockito.anyString())
      .thenReturn(configFile);
```

See: [`Mockito.anyString()`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/Matchers.html#anyString())